# Adding a button after listing all children in ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, view, expandablelistview, children

I'm making an app that creates an expandable list with various items in children list. My problem is that i want to add a button preferably after all children or as a last child of each group but when i try to do it the list glitches after i open any other group of children adding ton of buttons instead of one per each list on last position.
What i have in files is:

main_activity.java + xml,

child.xml,

group.xml,

ExpandListAdapter.java

This is how the code looks right now in the relevant section:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (isLastChild == true) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater2 = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater2.inflate(R.layout.button, null);
        }


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
            tv.setText(child.getName().toString());


        }



    return convertView;

}
```

I have noticed that each time a new group is opened entire view with all its children reinflates so can it be an issue with convertView still having the said button in its memory?

I have tried to move the button into the second "**if**" using same inflater then, but the same exact thing has happened, buttons seemingly randomly replace children of every group. I thought about adding the button manually maybe in the main activity but then again the child itself is convertView if i understand correctly so i can't really use that..

Is it worth trying to do this with ExpandableListView? Later i will want that button inside to add children to groups they are inside and additional button to remove them will this class be fine with it or will i have to do ton of gymnastics?

Thanks for all help, anything more i can add from the code please notify me and sorry for my bad english.